# How to tell which Xposed modules will break OTA updates?

Tags: ota-update, xposed-framework, mi-a1, magisk, systemless-root

I have Xiaomi MiA1 which being an Android one device gets monthly security updates

One can root it with Magisk and install systemless Xposed <sup>1</sup> . So far, good. My problem is with Xposed modules and not the framework since it's systemless.

Some modules likes adaway *write* to the hosts files in `/system` , so that will break OTA. Quoting from [Magisk on Github](https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/blob/master/docs/tips.md#ota-installation-tips)

> NOTE: In order to apply OTAs, you HAVE to make sure you haven't modified `/system` (and `/vendor` if available) in anyway, even remounting the partition to `rw` will tamper block verification!!

**How do I tell which Xposed modules will break OTA? <sup>2</sup>**

I am pretty confused

---

<sup>1</sup> Magisk with it's modules passes CTS checks and with Xposed fails as is documented. So I plan to disable Xposed before updating to pass CTS and get OTA. There are ways of doing this and yet get OTA which I intend to try

<sup>2</sup> Asking on their module threads doesn't seem to help  . If it matters, Gravity Box, Xprivacy Lua, Greenify, No Lock Home, Amplify are the ones I am currently interested in

---

Comment: My guess is there is no way to tell beforehand but to experiment. Wondering if there is an easy way

Comment: If you use Magisk (I do), AdAway will only "think" to write to `/system` – but Magisk masks that so in reality it writes into the folder provided by Magisk. I know that as I use both :) But I cannot tell whether Magisk masks that for *all* things there might be; especially for specific Xposed modules.

Comment: @Izzy: Yes, one can enable that option in Magisk , I noticed but that example was perhaps wrong. To give a better example, there is a Magisk module that *elevates* Greenify (which kept waking up screen every now and then so uninstalled ) but with limited functionality as against the Xposed (as claimed by the Magisk module Dev). That made me wonder if that *masking* is selective for only those Magisk mods who do things system-**lessly** :)

Comment: I suspect there are some such mods. But I fully agree with your initial comment: hard to know before one checks. Unless the dev explicitly states in the description, of course ;)